# Will this allow for mysql_real_escape_string to work globally?

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

```
$_POST = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST);
```

By executing this statement, does each post value now get escaped via `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Read it. Thanks for the double reminder.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

No. That won't work at all: `$_POST` is an array: `mysql_real_escape_string` needs a string as its first argument.  You can, however, achieve what you want with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
```

Or [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) as `array_map` does not work on array post values:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, function(&$v, $k) {$v = mysql_real_escape_string($v);});
```

Better, however, would be to use paramaterised queries: this is by far the most secure way to avoid SQL injection. Not only does the above option do needless escaping (for instance, members of the `$_POST` array that don't need to be inserted into the database), it also makes it harder to use the data in other contexts, e.g. returning them to the browser in some way.

Comment: Indeed, answer updated to reflect this, and Damien's correct answer upvoted. The other caution still applies.

Comment: Sure, I think the other caution is the real caution, mapping the array I think is not healing the cause, there is no silver bullet.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use [`array_walk()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_walk) or [`array_walk_recursive()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) to achieve that, as [`mysql_real_escape_string()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) requires a string (go figure...) as input, and you're passing it an array instead.
With this, you pass each array element the same callback function:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'escape');

escape($k,$v)
{
 return mysql_real_escape_string($v);
}
```

**But it's better to treat each value accordingly**, for ex. casting an INT to INT, etc., or better yet, [**use parametrized queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @hakre thanks, feel free to edit my answer if you find errors

Answer (score 0):

Since $_POST is an array, this will going to give you an error.

link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score -2):

$escapedPost = array_map(array($this, 'recursive_escape'), $_POST);

```
/**
 * recursively escape an array containing strings and/or arrays
 */
function recursive_escape($value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        array_map(array($this, 'recursive_escape'), $value);
    } else {
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: This function should never be used, as it revives magic quotes feature, already removed from the language.